# Bad chunk header load testing - jmeter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jmeter

Getting below when run load testing using jmeter, but when check on server log no any exceptions and it has returns response succefully into Jmeter. What could be the issue here.

```
<responseData 
 class="java.lang.String">org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Bad chunk 
header: 
{&quot;...<<My Response>>;
,&quot;desc&quot;:&quot;Success&quot;}}    
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.getChunkSize(ChunkedInputStream.java:274)    
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.nextChunk(ChunkedInputStream.java:222)    
at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:183)    
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:135)    
at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:148)    

at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1944)    
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:476)    
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:677)    
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)    
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)    
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1290)    
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)    
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)   
 at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)    
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)    
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
</responseData>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [enable tracing requests and responses](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

This way you will see what's happening on network level when you're sending and receiving the requests in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Most probably JMeter expects a [chunked response](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.html#section-3.6.1) and instead gets something like closed connection or [connection reset](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed).

Check out [Bad chunk header mystery](https://medium.com/@rey5137/bad-chunk-header-mystery-3ac26c21875f) article for example investigation